# How to resize JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I made a login dialog using a `JOptionPane`.

The dialog contains a custom `JPanel` and custom `JButton` components.

I want to display a message at the bottom (`SOUTH`) of the panel when the user enters an incorrect password.

To display that message I use a custom `JLabel`.

Problem: when the message is displayed the buttons get 'pushed' down and are no longer fully inside the option pane. Ideally the option pane would automatically resize to accommodate the new size of the panel.

I can set the `preferredSize` of the label to match the `Font` I'm using in it and the number of lines I want to display in the label, e.g. font size 10 and one line of text `setPreferredSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 10)`, 2 lines of text `setPreferredSize(Integer.Min_Value, 20)` etc.

Downsides:

1) When the message is not displayed the empty label takes up more space than I'd like.

I tried `JOptionPane.getRootFrame.pack()`. Did not work.

The code below (SSCC) shows what I mean. If you click 'login' the errorLabel text is set and buttons will be 'pushed' down.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoginDialog {

    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JLabel errorLabel;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public LoginDialog(){
    }


    private JPanel createMainPanel(){

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        mainPanel.add(createLabelsPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(createTextFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);


        errorLabel=new JLabel();
        errorLabel.setFont(new Font(errorLabel.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 10));
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        errorLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        errorLabel.setText("");
        mainPanel.add(errorLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createLabelsPanel(){

        JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Username", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Password", SwingConstants.RIGHT));

        return labelsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextFieldsPanel(){

        JPanel textFieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));

        usernameField = new JTextField();
        passwordField = new JPasswordField();

        textFieldsPanel.add(usernameField);
        textFieldsPanel.add(passwordField);

        return textFieldsPanel;
    }

    private JButton[] createButtons() {

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                errorLabel.setText("<html> More than two <BR> lines of text <BR> </html>");
            }
        });

        JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");


        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

        return new JButton[]{loginButton, registerButton, cancelButton};
    }


    private void showAndCreateDialog() {

        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, createMainPanel(), "Login", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, createButtons(), createButtons()[0]);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new LoginDialog().showAndCreateDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Buttons get 'pushed' down and are no longer shown fully within the option pane. Would like to learn how to resize option pane to accommodate new `JPanel` dimensions.

Comment: *"How to resize JOptionPane?"* Put more/less or larger/smaller components in it.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In this case that means not so much 'taking more out' as 'adding in what's needed for us to run it'. But first thoughts, don't use a custom label (just like you're not using custom buttons or panels). If useful, have a factory method for returning instances of the label configured as needed. I'd design the method call to take a `String` for the content. Set that when it is created and leave the size to the label / layout. (If that's not the solution, please clarify why not.)

Comment: Methods `setFont()`, `setForeground()`, `setPreferredSize()`, `setHorizontalAlignment()` and `setText()` are all _public_ methods. No real need to create a class that extends `JLabel`. Also, why not extend `JDialog` for your login dialog, rather than `JOptionPane`. As they say, the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! I extended JLabel because I want to use the same kind of label in a RegistrationDialog. Is that not good DRY practice? Ill try to provide an SSCC.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pack the dialog after showing you will need access to the actual `JDialog`. This can be done by adding a new attribute dialog and replacing the `showOptionDialog` with

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(createMainPanel(),
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
    createButtons(), createButtons()[0]);
dialog = pane.createDialog("Login");
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

then you can simply call `dialog.pack()` after setting the text and the dialog will resize.

Note: The default option object has to be contained in the options array, if you call createButtons() twice it will be a different object and won't work, instead store the options like this:

```
JButton[] buttons = createButtons();
JOptionPane pane =
    new JOptionPane(createMainPanel(), JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[0]);
```

Comment: After running `dialog.setVisible(true)`, how do you know which option the user chose?